# What is user agent string for iOS 7.0.4

Tags: ios

I need to emulate iOS 7.0.4 behavior on my Safari desktop by changing the user agent string. The options in Safari are only available for iOS 4.3.3 as shown below

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5
```

Is it possible to modify this to iOS7 behavior?

Comment: Use a network sniffer like Charles Proxy (free trial) to see what is being sent by an iOS device, it is a little extra setup but not that bad and there are good instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) (free trial) to see exactly what is being sent. In my case it is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11

As should be obvious this will change with each version of Safari.

The user agent string  can be set in the `NSMutableURLRequest` by setting the header field for the key: @"User-Agent".

```
[mutableURLRequest setValue:@"SPECIAL USER AGENT STRING" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Comment: I can add the user Agent through Desktop safari by using developer tools but I neeed to know the exact string to be used as user agent for Mobil Safari on iOS 7

Comment: You can use Charles Proxy to see what is being sent by an iOS device, it is a little extra setup but not that bad and there are good instructions.